# Change the value of a column using gsub

Tags: unix, awk

I have to change all the values of the first column of a file (exempt for the header) using a unix command.

I try the following but it seems it's deleting everything on my file :

```
awk -F\| -v val="20190306" '{gsub($1,val); print}' file > file
```

Also, `20190306` is normally a variable, I replaced with an example of a value. I would like to be able to put this variable in a date format, like `2019-03-06` instead of `20190306`.

My input is :

```
Value_date; CPTY 2018-10-17;INVEST 2018-10-17;USD
```

The output I want is :

```
Value_date; CPTY 2019-03-06;INVEST 2019-03-06;USD
```

My awk version is : 3.1.7

Comment: Do you mean the value of the first column must be set to the `val`?

Comment: Yes exactly. I should also change the val because it is of format YYYYMMDD, and I want format YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: You'd need a `gensub` if you want to format that string since  `gsub` does not support backreferences in the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F\| -v val="20190306" '{gsub($1,val); print}' file > file
# ......................................................^^^^^^
```

You file is getting truncated to zero length **before** the awk command even starts. Then shell processes  redirections *first*.

You need to output to a temp file, and then move the temp file to the original *if* the awk command succeeded:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
awk ... file > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file
```

There are other techniques you can use:

- install the `moreutils` package, then `awk ... file | sponge file`

Comment: I tried this but it deleted the header and the column (except for the first one with the value I wanted) : tmp=$(mktemp) && awk -F\| -v val="20190306" 'NR>1 {gsub($1,val); print}' file > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file

Comment: I was just addressing the shell error. The main problem is that you're only printing inside the `NR > 1` block. You want `awk -F'|' -v val=whatever 'NR>1 {$1 = val} 1'`. To explain the trailing "1", see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Answer (score 0):

You misled us with your own code, and no sample input and output...
Base on the input and out you showed in comments, I believe this better use sed:

```
val='20190306'
sed -e 's/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}/'"${val:0:4}-${val:4:2}-${val:6:2}"'/g' file
```

Or in this case, this work too:

```
sed -e "s/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}/${val:0:4}-${val:4:2}-${val:6:2}/g" file
```

When the output seems fine, add `-i` switch (`sed -i -e ...`) to change the file inplace.

If you want to use awk:

```
awk -v newd="${val:0:4}-${val:4:2}-${val:6:2}" '{gsub(/[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/, newd);}1' file
```

But since you don't have `GNU awk v4.1.0+`, you can't use `-i inplace` to change in place.
You can try:

```
awk -v newd="${val:0:4}-${val:4:2}-${val:6:2}" '{gsub(/[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/, newd);}1' file | tee file
```

If it's not working, you'll have to use temporary file instead, like this:

```
awk -v newd="${val:0:4}-${val:4:2}-${val:6:2}" '{gsub(/[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/, newd);}1' file > temp_file
mv -f temp_file file
```

Comment: I tried this but it deletes everything in the file again : 
awk -F\| -v val="20190306" '$1=val' file | tee file

I can't use the inplace function because of my GNU.
Sorry there must be something I don't understand.

Comment: My input is : 
Value_date; CPTY
2018-10-17;INVEST
2018-10-17;USD

Comment: The output I want is : 
Value_date; CPTY
2019-03-06;INVEST
2019-03-06;USD

Comment: Sorry @Tiw my awk version is : 3.1.7

Comment: @GuillaumeC Updated. Next time please include sample input and expected output in your question.